# How to make multi-page nested table?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, nesting

I generate a LaTeX document automatically.

So I need to make a table that can be nested in another table, and provides multipaging.  `{tabular}` - can be nested, but not multipaged
`{longtable}` - is multipaged, but doesn't allow nesting.

So my variant now is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
  TT            &  TT  \\ 
  Image element &  \begin{longtable} {ccc}
                              TT  &  TT  \\ 
                    Image element & ne
                  \end{longtable} 
\end{longtable} 

\end{document}
```

and for sure it fails with a error:

```
! Argument of \LT@nofcols has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8          Image element &  \begin{longtable} {ccc}
```

So how to make a nested table with multi-paging?

Comment: Welcome! Please post complete code we can fail to compile just like you. If you get an error, include the text of the error message. However, I'm not sure that what you want is possible. You could nest a `tabular` in a `longtable`, but if that's not enough I seriously doubt you can do this automatically. Maybe with Lua. I wouldn't know about that. But `longtable` already does serious things to get things to work. I don't see how it could work to nest it.

Comment: Maybe have a think about non-tabular environments, would be my suggestion. Hard to say without knowing what you're trying to do. (That is, why you think you *need* nested multipage tabulars.) You could break them as images, of course, but that can easily mean a break through the middle of a line.

Comment: @cfr I need automaticly generate a grid, that can have a nested grid or text/image in each cell. Nesting level doesn't limited. And for sure content size is unknown before generation.

Comment: I don't think this can even work in theory. `longtable` does not break inside a row or cell, so if your `image elements` are too big to fit on a page, `longtable` might never find a break point.  I think you're better off using a package like `adjustbox`, but I don't know what you mean by 'grid'. (It reminds me, though, of those dark days of the internet when seemingly all webpages secretly used tables to force absolute positioning ... and no one wants to go back there!)

Comment: @jon yes, you are so right ) i need to position elements in the document, and don't know how to do it correctly. All i have suggested - is to make a grid and place elements there.

Comment: People might be able to suggest other ways to accomplish your goal if you can give more details (and maybe an image) of what you need to achieve.