# how to make the architecture for the auto-generated doc?

Tags: tables, positioning, data-structures

I need to generate LaTeX automatically. The user can consider to paste an element to any place of the document and then the TeX version is generated.

Now I considered to describe a document as a nested structure: document has a "rows" , "rows" has a "cells" and cells contains text or table or image, or another "rows".

But when I'm trying to convert this structure to LaTeX I have a problem - nested tables can't be multi-paged.

So I need another doc architecture?
Can you suggest how to solve this task?

Comment: About that kind of document are we talking? Mabye [doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) serves your needs?

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question as the other one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360943/how-to-make-multi-page-nested-table ???

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, but previous question doesn't have an answer. So i'm trying to change a question

Comment: @Mira: Well, why not change the other question then? As long as there is no answer there's no harm done in changing the question.